# random err 404 runtime.js angular in production

Tags: node.js, angular, google-app-engine, deployment

I am creating an angular app with a node server, which is deployed on GAE. Everything works fine but out of sudden, randomly an err 404 pops up and the site doesn't load, unless I completely clear out my cache. This is not an one off scenario and happens randomly. I can't pinpoint the error though. My app works just fine when using locally and while running it through the server after building it for prod.

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.use(express.json())
const allowedExt = [
  '.js',
  '.ico',
  '.css',
  '.png',
  '.jpg',
  '.woff2',
  '.woff',
  '.ttf',
  '.svg',
  '.gif',
  '.GIF'
];
//hopefully solving syntax error
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.url);

      if (allowedExt.filter(ext => req.url.indexOf(ext) > 0).length > 0) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,`angularFront/dist/${req.url}`));
      } else {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'angularFront/dist/index.html'));
      }
});

var server = app.listen(process.env.port || 8080, function () {
  console.log('Listening');
  var port = server.address().port;
});
```

It has CI/CD enabled so nothing works manually or is prone to human errors. I do think its an issue either with my server file/ deploying procedure/ GAE issue. The following is my script for running it

```
npm install && ng build --prod --source-map=false --crossOrigin=use-credentials
```

Comment: what do you mean by `an err 404 pops up` and later `My app works just fine  ... while running it through the server after building it for prod.`? Have you set up expiration times for the static files? Could you share the app entrypoint from your app.yaml?

Comment: No expiration time was set, but the thing is how do we know when our next release will be there. This is an issue with js files only.

Answer (score 0):

I think the 404 Not Found errors are related to both the CI/CD pipeline and the expiration time for static files. By [default](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#static_cache_expiration) all static files are given a expiration deadline of 10 minutes, which helps reducing page load latency by caching. When the app is built Angular generates the minified JS files and the name of these files usually changes. Then, when the CI/CD pipeline deploys a new version of the website it may happen some user requests and old version of the file which happens not to be there anymore. This fact is explained in the section [Splitting Traffic](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/splitting-traffic) of the documentation, which also outlines some techniques that might be used to handle the transition between static files that differ across versions.